# What type of sampling method is it if I choose people who are between 18-22 and speak a specific language?

Tags: sampling, terminology, population

I would like to know how it is called as a sampling technique when I need people that are between certain age range and able to speak German. The research is an experiment and people are asked on the street if they want to participate or not. Then, I ask if they are between 18-22 and if they can speak German. I ask people who I think they are between 18-22 in order to be more efficient and save time. Is it called homogeneous sampling (purposive) because research is all about people who are between 18-22? Or convenience sampling?

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is not about sampling but about the inclusion criteria for your study. Are you screening everybody and then just recruiting those aged 18 to 22 and speaking German?

Comment: Yes, I would look at people in the street, if they seem young and seem to be between 18-22, I would go and ask their age and also if they know German because the questionnaire will be in German. When they fit well, I would ask if they would like to participate to this experiment.

Comment: @mdewey forgot to tag sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be an example of quota sampling, at least not from the limited information you give. You may be confusing your ***population of interest*** with the sampling method, in fact.

Quota sampling is similar to stratified sampling, in that you are essentially reproducing the composition of a wider population, except (unlike in stratified sampling) you don't have known probabilities for each individual in advance. If you were studying some population of interest and German speakers aged 18-22 within that population were a group of interest that you wanted to study, you would set a quota for them and continue interviewing German speakers aged 18-22 until you have filled the quota—that would be quota sampling.

However, it sounds like ***German speakers aged 18-22 are your entire population of interest***; i.e., you are only interested in them. Now, whether your sampling is purposive or not depends on how you select your subjects / participants. Purposive sampling usually involves a subjective decision by the researcher to include an individual in the sample, and it is usually done when both the population of interest and the sample are small. For example, if you are studying German speakers aged 18-22 in, e.g., Britain or in one town or in one university, maybe you will collect your sample through a personal network or by snowball technique. In these cases, you would know your population of interest is relatively small, so probability sampling would not be adequate. However, I'm wondering if you're interested in all German speakers aged 18-22 in the world (including those in countries where German is an official language). That's a lot of individuals, so keep in mind that purposive sampling may not be an adequate sampling method to say something about them, especially if your research is quantitative and you want to obtain some point estimates.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, I need to provide more information. Actually this is an experiment and participants were stopped and asked face to face if they fit for these criteria. They need to speak German in order to fill in the questionnaires, I ask this just to eliminate those who don't speak and this way I would not lose time. About the age, the study investigates behavior of people who are between 18 and 22. So if they don't fit these criteria, they were simply not allowed to participate. I need to ask many people until I reach the limit of people  that I want to do the experiment with.

Comment: The commenters have it correct.  The population you are interested in speaking about is the population of German-speakers between 18 and 22 years of age.  The choice of those parameters is not related to sampling - it defines who you are interested in.  Sampling refers to how you select people within the population you are interested in.  In your case, it sounds like you are selecting the individuals within that population that you find easy to get to - so convenience sampling would be what you are doing.

Comment: @Ken read J Taylor comment above.

Comment: @JTaylor you can tag users like I do immediately above.

Comment: @gRRRR forgot to tag you, sorry!